# I am facing issue in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, async-await, itext

When I call the document.Add(table) and then I face this issue. This is generated for random values not for a specific one. Sometimes this method works for value but some time for the same value it throws below exception.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:   

    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable.RowSpanAbove(Int32 currRow, Int32 currCol)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable.GetRowHeight(Int32 idx, Boolean firsttime)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.GoComposite(Boolean simulate)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.ColumnText.Go(Boolean simulate)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.AddPTable(PdfPTable ptable)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Add(IElement element)
   at iTextSharp.text.Document.Add(IElement element)
```

Comment: It might be possible that your iTextSharp Document object may be null. Can you please share the code as well from where you are getting this error?

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:async-await]. Your question, though, in no way refers to that. So, why that tag?

Answer (score 0):

I dig down the library and found the issue that the library has some limitations to write large data. Previously we are using iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.6.3 which has some limitations. Now I update on iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 1.6.7 and it's working fine